# Gradle build failing for Android Studio without any code changes

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I am facing a strange issue. The same code base was working few days ago but today breaking with below error.

```
Could not find matching constructor for: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.VersionInfo(String)
```

I am not able to find the reason behind this error. It would be really helpful if any of you can help.

Please find below are the required informations.

dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.appCompatVersion}"
    implementation "com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:${rootProject.ext.crashlyticsVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${rootProject.ext.appCompatVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:${rootProject.ext.constraintLayoutVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${rootProject.ext.appCompatVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${rootProject.ext.appCompatVersion}"
    implementation "com.onesignal:OneSignal:${rootProject.ext.onesignalVersion}"
    implementation "com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:${rootProject.ext.kenburnsViewVersion}"
    implementation "com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:${rootProject.ext.firebaseJobDispatcherVersion}"
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:${rootProject.ext.glideVersion}"

    //google admob
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1'
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:${rootProject.ext.room_version}"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:${rootProject.ext.room_version}"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:${rootProject.ext.lifecycle_version}"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:${rootProject.ext.lifecycle_version}"

    //below is for app tutor view
    implementation "com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:${rootProject.ext.showcaseViewVersion}"

    //below two dependencies are for circular image transformation to gif by glide
    implementation "jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:${rootProject.ext.glideTransformationsVersion}"
    implementation 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.4.1'

    //below dependency is for bookmark star animation
    implementation "com.github.varunest:sparkbutton:${rootProject.ext.sparkButtonVersion}"

    //below dependency is for button with validation animation
    implementation "com.unstoppable:submitbutton:${rootProject.ext.submitButtonVersion}"

    //dependency for firebase auth
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-people:v1-rev4-1.22.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'

    //dependency for firebase db
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2'

    //for signin button google custom
    implementation "com.shobhitpuri.custombuttons:google-signin:${rootProject.ext.googleSigninButtonVersion}"

    //youtube
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')

    //support
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${rootProject.ext.appCompatVersion}"

    //webview
    implementation "com.thefinestartist:finestwebview:${rootProject.ext.fineWebviewVersion}"

    //speech to text module
    implementation project(path: ':speech-to-text', configuration: 'default')

    //viewmodel and livedata
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:${rootProject.ext.lifecycle_version}"
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    //memory leaks detection
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.6.3'
    releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.6.3'

    // Optional, if you use support library fragments:
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-support-fragment:1.6.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    //lottie
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.0'
}
```

Versions:

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion=28
    minSdkVersion=19
    targetSdkVersion=28
    materialDesignVersion='1.0.0'
    appCompatVersion='28.0.0'
    crashlyticsVersion='2.9.9'
    constraintLayoutVersion='1.1.3'
    onesignalVersion='3.9.1'
    glideVersion='4.9.0'
    firebaseJobDispatcherVersion='0.8.5'
    kenburnsViewVersion='1.0.6'
    room_version='1.1.1'
    lifecycle_version='1.1.1'
    fineWebviewVersion='1.2.7'
    showcaseViewVersion='5.4.3'
    glideTransformationsVersion='3.3.0'
    sparkButtonVersion='1.0.5'
    submitButtonVersion='1.1.3'
    googleSigninButtonVersion='1.0.0'
    lifecycle_version="1.1.1"
}
```

I am using Gradle version of 3.4.1
I tried clean project, rebuild project, invalidate cache and restart. None of it helped.

P.S: I have looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55548505/could-not-find-matching-constructor-for-org-gradle-api-internal-artifacts-ivyse) question already and I am using OneSignal and I need it.

Comment: Try running gradle with `--stacktrace` to help see where the error is occurring. It's possibly occurring inside one of the plugins you've applied to your project

Comment: @lance-java, yes. I tried it already and got below exception

Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.VersionInfo(String)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1749)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1556)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.MetaClassConstructorSite.callConstructor(MetaClassConstructorSite.java:48)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:249)
...

Comment: You've truncated the stacktrace. Ultimately we're looking for a line number in a plugin or in your build.gradle

Comment: @lance-java, added more stack trace. Looks like it is caused due to OneSignal library.

Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.VersionInfo(java.lang.String)
        at com.onesignal.androidsdk.GradleProjectPlugin.compareVersions(GradleProjectPlugin.groovy:145)
        at

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `OneSignal` plugin is using internal gradle APIs (VersionInfo is under the org.gradle.api.internal package). Unlike the public Gradle APIs, the Gradle team can change internal APIs without warning and make no guarantees that they won't have breaking changes between Gradle versions.

Perhaps you're on an old version of the `OneSignal` plugin which is now broken with your newer version of Gradle. Perhaps there's a newer version of the plugin which will work?

Failing that you could track down the plugin author and submit a bug to the project, or perhaps submit a pull request with a fix

Comment: Hey @lance-java, yes I contacted the team for support. Looks like there is a change in their sdk implementation and it was breaking for the reason that I was using old way of implementation. I will update the answer with fix. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Another option is to keep using the same version of the `OneSignal` plugin but change your gradle version to be compatible. I'm guessing that would mean using an older version of Gradle

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it finally. Below is the fix I found after contacting OneSignal support.

Cause: Changes from OneSignal affected it.

Fix:
1. The way we implement OneSignal SDK has been changed and it was not notified to the users. Earlier, below was the first step of implementation.

```
plugins {
id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin' version '0.7.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
```

Now, you need to change it to

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.12.2'
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
```

Making above will fix the error. However, I had to then migrate my project to androidX too.
so,
2. Migrate project to androidX.

above two steps fixed the bug.